# not understanding a question about IVT

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image: question]

Hello, I do not understand why the first answer is correct : in fact the intermediate value theorem only yields that there exists a $u$ such that $\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{8}=f'(u)...$

Comment: $f'(u)=\frac{f(\pi/4)-f(0)}{\pi/4-0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there is $u \in ]0, \pi/4[$ such that

$$\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=f( \pi/4)-f(0)=f'(u)(\frac{\pi}{4}-0).$$

Comment: woops sorry for the dumb question its the pre-exam stress

Answer (score 2):

On $]0,\pi/4[$ we have $f(u)=u \cos u$ and $f'(u)=\cos u-u \sin u$

As $f'(u)$ is continuous, $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(\pi/4)\approx 0.15$, fot the IVT there exists at least one $u\in]0,\pi/4[$ such that $f'(u)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$